# Way to make query with inner join, for update of X skip locked, ordering and limit

Tags: postgresql, distinct, select-for-update

I need to acquire N records of table `X`, but I need to filter these records using an INNER JOIN, and order them on the joined records accordingly beforehand.

Example of what I tried to do (might not be 100% exact, as I'm using SQLAlchemy):

```
SELECT X.id
FROM X
   INNER JOIN Y ON X.id = Y.other_id
WHERE Y.condition_one
ORDER BY Y.condition_two
LIMIT 10
FOR UPDATE OF X SKIP LOCKED;
```

When I do this, I am getting fewer than 10 distinct `id`s (probably because the joined rows are limited), however, I cannot execute `DISTINCT` with 
`FOR UPDATE`. I think I can't use a subquery, because of `FOR UPDATE`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had trouble with using DISTINCT and ORDER BY at the same time.

The LATERAL join should have worked in theory, but while working on an implementation, I found another approach:

```sql
SELECT X.id
FROM X
   JOIN (SELECT X.id, MIN(Y.condition_two) AS ordering
         FROM X
            INNER JOIN Y ON X.id = Y.other_id
         WHERE Y.condition_one) AS sub_x
      ON X.id = sub_x.id
ORDER BY ASC(sub_x.ordering)
LIMIT 10
FOR UPDATE OF X SKIP LOCKED;
```

If I wanted to order using DESC, I would have to change MIN to MAX.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a lateral join:

```
SELECT X.id
FROM X
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT Y.condition_two
      FROM Y
      WHERE X.id = Y.other_id
        AND Y.condition_one
      ORDER BY Y.condition_two
      LIMIT 1) AS first_y
ORDER BY first_y.condition_two
LIMIT 10
FOR UPDATE OF X SKIP LOCKED;
```

Or (simpler) use a subselect with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT X.id
FROM X
   JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT X.id
         FROM X
            INNER JOIN Y ON X.id = Y.other_id
         WHERE Y.condition_one
         ORDER BY Y.condition_two
         LIMIT 10) AS sub_x
      ON X.id = sub_x.id
FOR UPDATE OF X SKIP LOCKED;
```

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz, your answer unblocked my mind, and let me work it out for myself :-)